# FFMPEG for Android toolchains: arm-linux-armeabi-eabi-pkg-config - is there any toolchain in existence containing the pkg-config tool

Tags: android, compilation, ffmpeg, static-libraries, linux-toolchain

Does anybody know  any toolchain for **ffmpeg linux arm**  platform which contains the **arm-linux-androideabi-pkg-config** tool? 
The Android NDK does not contain it. Also has anybody succeeded in building ffmpeg for android that contains the alsa device? Please note that libasound is present on my Ubuntu x86 PC.
After very extensive research visiting forums including ffmpeg.org, ffmpeg--nabbles, groups.google.com including the andro and android-ndk gropus, and the Internet in general, I have not succeeded in finding anyone who seems to know of its existence. At best, I have read people saying ignore it. Considering what it is needed for, I consider that a naive thing to say.
A careful review of the standard ffmpeg configure script shows that for certain input and output devices  a toolchain described as **pkg_config_default=pkg-config** is required. Also all items on the HAVE_LIST are SYSTEM DEPENDENT. The configure script states very clearly what dependencies are required for each indev  or outdev item. Apparently this tool is used then to verify the libraries which are needed for the dependencies
This is what happens when you attempt to configure ffmpeg for android

> jasongipsyblues@android-master:~/android-ffmpeg/Project/jni$ ./configure_ffmpeg.sh
> ...
> ...
> ..
> ....
> License: GPL version 3 or later
>   Creating config.mak and config.h...
>
> config.h is unchanged
>
> config.asm is unchanged
>
> libavutil/avconfig.h is unchanged
>
> WARNING: /home/jasongipsyblues/Desktop/apps/android-ndk-r8b/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-
>   4.4.3/prebuilt/linux-x86/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-pkg-config not found, library detection may 
>   fail.

On a PC with Ubuntu there is no issue with pkg-config.
Please compare the following outputs when one greps for the in/out device  alsa from the config.log files for an Ubuntu x86 PC and that for the android box using the android-ndk-r8 toolchain

> jasongipsyblues@android-master:~/android-ffmpeg/Project/jni/ffmpeg$ cat config.log|grep >alsa
>      alsa_indev
>      alsa_outdev
>      alsa_asoundlib_h
>   INDEV_LIST='alsa_indev
>   OUTDEV_LIST='alsa_outdev
>   alsa_indev='yes'
>   alsa_indev_deps='alsa_asoundlib_h snd_pcm_htimestamp'
>   alsa_outdev='yes'
>   alsa_outdev_deps='alsa_asoundlib_h'
>   indevs_if_any='alsa_indev
>   outdevs_if_any='alsa_outdev
>   check_lib2 alsa/asoundlib.h snd_pcm_htimestamp -lasound
>   check_func_headers alsa/asoundlib.h snd_pcm_htimestamp -lasound
>      1  #include 
>   /tmp/ffconf.VCjQQAHQ.c:1:28: error: alsa/asoundlib.h: No such file or directory

This is the compiler output showing the source of the error:

> check_lib2 alsa/asoundlib.h snd_pcm_htimestamp -lasound
>   check_func_headers alsa/asoundlib.h snd_pcm_htimestamp -lasound
>   check_ld cc -lasound
>   check_cc
>   BEGIN /tmp/ffconf.VCjQQAHQ.c
>      1  #include 
>      2  long check_snd_pcm_htimestamp(void) { return (long) snd_pcm_htimestamp; }
>      3  int main(void) { return 0; }
>   END /tmp/ffconf.VCjQQAHQ.c
>   /home/jasongipsyblues/Desktop/apps/android-ndk-r8b/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi->4.4.3/prebuilt/linux-x86/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-gcc --sysroot=/home/jasongipsyblues/Desktop/apps/android-ndk-r8b/platforms/android-14/arch-arm -D_ISOC99_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_POSIX_C_SOURCE=200112 -D_XOPEN_SOURCE=600 -DPIC -I../x264 -mcpu=cortex-a9 -std=c99 -fomit-frame-pointer -fPIC -marm -c -o /tmp/ffconf.I2B2AXfH.o 
>   /tmp/ffconf.VCjQQAHQ.c
>   /tmp/ffconf.VCjQQAHQ.c:1:28: error: alsa/asoundlib.h: No such file or directory
>   /tmp/ffconf.VCjQQAHQ.c: In function 'check_snd_pcm_htimestamp':
>   /tmp/ffconf.VCjQQAHQ.c:2: error: 'snd_pcm_htimestamp' undeclared (first use in this function)
>   /tmp/ffconf.VCjQQAHQ.c:2: error: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once
>   /tmp/ffconf.VCjQQAHQ.c:2: error: for each function it appears in.)
>   This is for the Ubuntu x86PC ffmpeg 
>   jasongipsyblues@android-master:~/ffmpeg$ cat config.log|grep alsa
>      alsa_indev
>      alsa_outdev
>      alsa_asoundlib_h
>   INDEV_LIST='alsa_indev
>   OUTDEV_LIST='alsa_outdev
>   alsa_indev='yes'
>   alsa_indev_deps='alsa_asoundlib_h snd_pcm_htimestamp'
>   alsa_outdev='yes'
>   alsa_outdev_deps='alsa_asoundlib_h'
>   indevs_if_any='alsa_indev
>   outdevs_if_any='alsa_outdev
>   check_lib2 alsa/asoundlib.h snd_pcm_htimestamp -lasound
>   check_func_headers alsa/asoundlib.h snd_pcm_htimestamp -lasound
>      1  #include 
>  
>   There is no error here and alsa is successfully included in the ffmpeg build

Comment: Did you find any solution to resolve really this warning?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://github.com/guardianproject/android-ffmpeg

https://github.com/guardianproject/android-ffmpeg/commit/f08db49e613a7ea4423effb22973e3f1afefb819

look at the links. he just did a commit , including 'freetype2' submodule, in order to get around the pkg-config issue.

Comment: @rowntreerob, thanks for this link. I did take a ollok at and have tried to understand what he is doing here. I still do have a number of questions. What is the ultimate result of running the fake-pkg-config? Does it attempt to build the library or provide the missing or necessary files needed directly to the compiler and linker.

Comment: no idea... i never pay attention to the compiler warnings on 'pkg-config'.