# Compiling FFmpeg lib and add it to NDK sources on Windows8

Tags: android-ndk, ffmpeg

I've seen some articles about how to compile and uses FFmpeg for Android.

These are 2 good examples - [example1](http://www.roman10.net/how-to-build-ffmpeg-with-ndk-r9/) and [example2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10665039/does-anyone-find-this-useful-compiling-ffmpeg-on-windows-with-cywin-and-ndk-r)

Unfortunately, non off them, or others I found helped me. In those two examples a build_android.sh is created and configure the FFmpeg's configuraion file and call to make. Every time when I'm running the script I'm getting the following error:

```
c:\android\development\android-ndk-r9\sources\ffmpeg>sh build_android.sh
c:/android/development/android-ndk-r9/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.8/prebu
ilt/windows-x86_64/arm-linux-androideabi/bin/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-gcc is un

able to create an executable file.
C compiler test failed.

If you think configure made a mistake, make sure you are using the latest
version from Git.  If the latest version fails, report the problem to the
ffmpeg-user@ffmpeg.org mailing list or IRC #ffmpeg on irc.freenode.net.
Include the log file "config.log" produced by configure as this will help
solving the problem.
Makefile:2: config.mak: No such file or directory
Makefile:49: /common.mak: No such file or directory
Makefile:92: /libavutil/Makefile: No such file or directory
Makefile:92: /library.mak: No such file or directory
Makefile:169: /doc/Makefile: No such file or directory
Makefile:170: /tests/Makefile: No such file or directory
make: *** No rule to make target `/tests/Makefile'.  Stop.
Makefile:2: config.mak: No such file or directory
```

If someone encountered and solved this issue it'll be much appreciated!

After trying the suggested script I ran into a new problem that I couldn't solved, this is the output of the script:

.... Enabled components list....

In the end of the list I got the following:

Enabled indevs:
dv1394                  v4l2i
fbdev

Enabled outdevs:
fbdev                   v4l2

License: LGPL version 2.1 or later
Creating config.mak, config.h, and doc/config.texi...

WARNING: C:/android/development/android-ndk-r9/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-
4.8/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-pkg-config not found, libr
ary detection may fail.
make: *** No rule to make target `libavfilter/libavfilter.so', needed by` all-ye
s'.  Stop.
make: *** No rule to make target `install-libavfilter-shared', needed by` instal
l-libs-yes'.  Stop.

Comment: Hi, I am trying to build ffmpeg the same way and process ending up with following errors:

Makefile:2: config.mak: No such file or directory 
Makefile:49: /common.mak: No such file or directory 
Makefile:92: /libavutil/Makefile: No such file or directory 
Makefile:92: /library.mak: No such file or directory 
Makefile:169: /doc/Makefile: No such file or directory 
Makefile:170: /tests/Makefile: No such file or directory

How to fix this issue???

Comment: seems to have been answered elsewhere: _[How to compile ffmpeg-2.2.2 on windows with cygwin and android ndk r9c](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23683518/how-to-compile-ffmpeg-2-2-2-on-windows-with-cygwin-and-android-ndk-r9c)_

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Can you paste what's in your build_android.sh file which you've copied inside the FFmpeg directory?

I've got the same error when one of the variables defined at the start of the script where set incorrectly. Check to see if your NDK or SYSROOT or TOOLCHAIN variables are set to a valid path!

I've tried using the following steps and it worked for me:

1) **Download FFmpeg**

> git clone git://source.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.git ffmpeg

2) **Create a file called build_android.sh inside the FFmpeg directory**

> cd ffmpeg; touch build_ffmpeg_for_android.sh;

3) **Add the following content to the file**

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

NDK=$HOME/Software/Android/android-ndk-r10/
SYSROOT=$NDK/platforms/android-19/arch-arm/
TOOLCHAIN=$NDK/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.8/prebuilt/linux-x86_64

function build_one
{
./configure \
    --prefix=$PREFIX \
    --enable-shared \
    --disable-static \
    --disable-doc \
    --disable-ffmpeg \
    --disable-ffplay \
    --disable-ffprobe \
    --disable-ffserver \
    --disable-avdevice \
    --disable-doc \
    --disable-symver \
    --cross-prefix=$TOOLCHAIN/bin/arm-linux-androideabi- \
    --target-os=linux \
    --arch=arm \
    --enable-cross-compile \
    --sysroot=$SYSROOT \
    --extra-cflags="-Os -fpic $ADDI_CFLAGS" \
    --extra-ldflags="$ADDI_LDFLAGS" \
    $ADDITIONAL_CONFIGURE_FLAG
make clean
make -j4
make install
}

CPU=arm
PREFIX=$(pwd)/android/$CPU
ADDI_CFLAGS="-marm"

build_one
```

4) **Make the script executable**

> chmod +x build_ffmpeg_for_android.sh

5) **Start the build of FFmpeg for Android (ARM)

(run the script with Bash, i.e. /usr/bin/bash not /usr/bin/sh)**

> ./build_ffmpeg_for_android.sh

Comment: Against which NDK version do you work? My NDK version is r9 and I keep getting in the end of the script error message:
"arm-linux-androideabi-pkg-config not found, library detection may faile", and then "nonexecstack: unknown -z option"

Comment: @powerX Android NDK r9b

Comment: thank you for the preciouse help, the above will be the answer probably. Even so I still have this problem and I think that it related to the fact that in my ndk folder I don't have "linux-x86_64" inside the "prebuilt" folder(I changed it in my script to "windows-x86_64")

Comment: FTI - added script results on my machine in the body of the question

Comment: @powerX Unfortunately the Windows Android NDK doesn't have **arm-linux-androideabi-pkg-config**. Does your Cygwin installation have **pkg-config** installed? It worked for me on a GNU/Linux system with only that installed... I think one of the above is required for building FFmpeg. As an alternative I suggest you look at this answer  http://stackoverflow.com/a/12144419/313113

Comment: This Solution for linux not for windows

Comment: The question for Compiling FFmpeg lib and add it to NDK sources on Windows8 not linux

Answer (score 1):

I was getting the same errors as @powerX and I was able to solve the issue using a different method from @dZkF9RWJT6wN8ux.

Though I am using Ubuntu 13.10, I hope you find my answer helpful. With android NDK r9 and FFMPEG 2.2 "Muybridge" release, I was finally able to accomplish the third step entitled "Build FFMPEG" from @powerX example1 link: http://www.roman10.net/how-to-build-ffmpeg-with-ndk-r9/

I finally fixed this by changing the SYSROOT variable in the build_android.sh file to point to ".../android-19/arch-arm" instead of .../android-9/arch-arm".

Hope this helps.