# How to compile ffmpeg-2.2.2 on windows with cygwin and android ndk r9c

Tags: android, windows, android-ndk, ffmpeg, cygwin

did someone successfully compile

ffmpeg-2.2.2 on windows with cygwin and android ndkr9c ?

Or can point me to an up to date tutorial ?

(http://www.roman10.net/how-to-build-ffmpeg-with-ndk-r9/ isn't working for me
i get Makefile:2: config.mak: No such file...
cygwin admin devel gnome is completely installed and make -v ok )

I need to convert a video to images(for live-wallpaper)... do you know a better
method or is ffmpeg the best ?

thx

Comment: Hello. Do you have some results? I mean build ffmpeg for android.

Comment: I did try https://github.com/guardianproject/android-ffmpeg 
https://github.com/wseemann/FFmpegMediaPlayer
https://github.com/roman10
https://code.google.com/p/android-fplayer/source/checkout
https://github.com/appunite/AndroidFFmpeg

Comment: Now is start a bounty to compile ffmpeg with audio video codec for android :)

Comment: I have done this! But under Ubuntu (Linux).

Comment: @VladimirKulyik: you're right, my favorite answer to the question _[how to build ffmpeg under Windows?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23683518/how-to-compile-ffmpeg-2-2-2-on-windows-with-cygwin-and-android-ndk-r9c)_ begins with words _[format your C: drive to ext4](http://askubuntu.com/questions/331353/how-to-replace-windows-with-ubuntu)._ This topic here is an exercise in cygwin trickery, irrelevant to 99.99% of SW developers.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Start with Roman's [tutorial](http://www.roman10.net/how-to-build-ffmpeg-with-ndk-r9/).
Following changes apply to Windows: you should use the **NDK** `make.exe`, not the one from **cygwin**. So, I simply wrote `d:/dev/Android/ndk/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/make.exe` in my **build_android.sh**. For some weird reason, I could not run `make clean` - but I simply chose to ignore this problem for now.

Following the tutorial, don't forget to set

```
TOOLCHAIN=$NDK/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.8/prebuilt/windows-x86_64
```

Also, use mixed-style paths, i.e. `d:/dev/whatever` and not **cygwin** style `/cygdrive/d/dev/whatever`. Be careful not to use paths with spaces - neither for **ndk** installation, nor for `ffmpeg` git clone.

With **ffmpeg 2.2**, you can use `--target-os=android` for `./configure`, instead of mangling `./configure` file as described in **step 2**.

On my machine, I did not have `pr` and `od` commands. I chose simply to fake them, writing

```
echo 'cat $3' > ./pr
echo 'echo od' > ./od
```

These do not spoil the build.

So, my build process is as follows:

```
git clean -d -f -x
./configure --enable-shared --disable-static --disable-doc --disable-ffmpeg --disable-ffplay --disable-ffprobe --disable-ffserver --disable-avdevice --disable-doc --disable-symver --cross-prefix=d:/android-ndk-r9c/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.8/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/arm-linux-androideabi- --target-os=android --arch=arm --enable-cross-compile --sysroot=d:/android-ndk-r9c/platforms/android-9/arch-arm/ --extra-cflags="-Os -fpic"
```

Compilation does display some warnings, but the **.so** files are all produced.

To enable NEON, I used

```
--extra-cflags="-Os -fpic -marm -march=armv7-a -mfloat-abi=softfp -mfpu=neon"
--extra-ldflags="-Wl,--fix-cortex-a8"
```

Now, `libavcodec.so` could not be built anymore: too many files on the linker list. <s>So, after it crashed, I launched the linker manually:</s>

```
$ d:/Dev/Android/ndk/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.8/prebuilt/windows-x86_64//bin/arm-linux-androideabi-gcc  -shared -Wl,-Bsymbolic -Wl,--version-script,libavcodec/libavcodec.ver -Llibavcodec -Llibavdevice -Llibavfilter -Llibavformat -Llibavresample -Llibavutil -Llibpostproc -Llibswscale -Llibswresample -Wl,--fix-cortex-a8  --sysroot=d:/Dev/Android/ndk/platforms/android-9/arch-arm/ -isysroot d:/Dev/Android/ndk/platforms/android-9/arch-arm/ -Wl,--as-needed -Wl,--warn-common -Wl,-rpath-link=libpostproc:libswresample:libswscale:libavfilter:libavdevice:libavformat:libavcodec:libavutil:libavresample @libavcodec/libavcodec.list -lswresample -lavutil -lm -lz -pthread -o libavcodec/libavcodec.so.55
```

I patch the `library.mak` file as follows: for `$(SUBDIR)$(SLIBNAME_WITH_MAJOR)`, replace

```
$$(LD) $(SHFLAGS) $(LDFLAGS) $$(LD_O) $$(filter %.o,$$^) $(FFEXTRALIBS)
```

with

```
$(Q)echo >$(SUBDIR)lib$(NAME).list $(wordlist 1,400,$(filter %.o,$$<))
$(Q)echo >>$(SUBDIR)lib$(NAME).list $(wordlist 401,999,$(filter %.o,$$<))
$$(LD) $(SHFLAGS) $(LDFLAGS) $$(LD_O) @$(SUBDIR)lib$(NAME).list $(FFEXTRALIBS)
```

.. and from there, `make` proceeded smoothly.

<s>**PS:** I used `make -n libavcodec/libavcodec.so.55` to prepare *the response file* `libavcodec/libavcodec.list`.</s>

**PPS:** Here is [another article](https://enoent.fr/blog/2014/06/20/compile-ffmpeg-for-android/) that helps to build and use ffmpeg for Android.

Comment: If it's not complicated for you. Can you post ready .sh file for windows?. And can I write C:/ndk/... instead of $NDK/... ? Ty for this answer.

Comment: @VladimirKulyik: `C:/ndk` is fine. Regarding `.sh` file, it won't be today, unfortunately.

Comment: Hi i made all like you did and i get  ./build_android.sh
d:/android-ndk-r9c/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.8/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-gcc is unable to create an executable file.
C compiler test failed.

Makefile:2: config.mak: No such file or directory
Makefile:58: /common.mak: No such file or directory
Makefile:98: /libavutil/Makefile: No such file or directory
Makefile:98: /library.mak: No such file or directory
Makefile:100: /doc/Makefile: No such file or directory
make: *** No rule to make target `/tests/Makefile'.  Stop.

Comment: did try it on ubuntu and same error .. can you help me please on skype elec_29a ?

Comment: I used roman10 tutorial On Ubuntu. Copy ffmpeg to ndk/sources. You should create .sh file on Linux , do not copy this file created on Windows. If you are using Ubuntux32: for TOOLCHAIN set linux-x86, else keep linux-x86_64. And before using .sh you should run: ./configure .And do not forget to give root accses for configure and .sh: sudo chmod 777 build_android.sh

Comment: Alex Cohn can you help me to solve this problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24330365/build-sdl-mixer-for-android

Comment: After the `./configure` failed (_unable to create an executable file_), the **make** files are not prepared, that's why you see all these errors with `Makefile`.

Comment: 'Alex Cohn' one more question. I have RunTimeError: could not load needed library 'libswresample.so' for 'libavcodec-55.so'. But I have loaded libswresample-0.so. So what is the problem?

Comment: @VladimirKulyik: did you use `--target-os=android`? Or you manually edited `./configure`? Or *both*?

Comment: I did finally install Ubuntu and MacOsx in Vmware and is compiling fine there... cygwin is a pain :(

Comment: c:/android-ndk-r10e/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9/prebuilt/windows/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-gcc is unable to create an executable file.
C compiler test failed.@AlexCohn

Comment: @SohailZahid most likely, `--enable-cross-compile` did not have effect

Comment: Regarding library.mak patch... There is missing ) at the end of the line $(Q)echo >>$(SUBDIR)lib$(NAME).list $(wordlist 401,999,$(filter %.o,$$<)

Answer (score 2):

You can use this as build_android.sh i tested it and it worked with me

```
#!/bin/bash
NDK=D:/android/ndk/android-ndk-r10d
SYSROOT=$NDK/platforms/android-8/arch-arm/
TOOLCHAIN=$NDK/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.8/prebuilt/windows
function build_one
{
./configure \
--prefix=$PREFIX \
--disable-shared \
--enable-static \
--disable-doc \
--disable-ffmpeg \
--disable-ffplay \
--disable-ffprobe \
--disable-ffserver \
--disable-avdevice \
--disable-doc \
--disable-symver \
--cross-prefix=$TOOLCHAIN/bin/arm-linux-androideabi- \
--target-os=linux \
--arch=arm \
--enable-cross-compile \
--sysroot=$SYSROOT \
--extra-cflags="-Os -fpic $ADDI_CFLAGS" \
--extra-ldflags="$ADDI_LDFLAGS" \
$ADDITIONAL_CONFIGURE_FLAG
make clean
make
make install
}
CPU=arm
PREFIX=$(pwd)/android/$CPU
ADDI_CFLAGS="-marm"
build_one
```

you need also to run this commands :

```
dos2unix build_android.sh
chmod +x build_android.sh
./build_android.sh
```

Use [this Tutorial](https://www.packtpub.com/sites/default/files/downloads/Developing_Multimedia_Applications_with_NDK.pdf) as reference

Comment: dos2unix and chmod exes are in C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin directory, how to use them inside ffmpeg folder ? I hate these cmd things...

Answer (score 1):

Build it on Ubuntu(Guest) and copy lib's(sub folder in /andoid-ndk/sources/ffmpeg/android) folder to Windows(Host).I tried it for Window but ended with lot of bugs, finally installed Ubuntu (Free) on virtualbox. also you willl have to download Andoid (SDK, Ndk) and JDK. This may sound weird but it worked for me.

Comment: Can you share your steps for compile and add it to android studio?