# How to compile ffmpeg-2.5.3 on windows with android-ndk-r10d

Tags: android, windows, android-ndk, ffmpeg

I am trying to compile FFMPEG for android on windows using android-ndk-10d. I have followed number of tutorials but I am unable to compile it.
Can any one please help me to compile FFMPEG. I have referred many blogs and tutorials but I am unable to retrieve the expected result.

I have used the following link [roman10](http://www.roman10.net/how-to-build-ffmpeg-with-ndk-r9/), but it isn't working.
Please help me.
Thank You

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to compile ffmpeg-2.2.2 on windows with cygwin and android ndk r9c](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23683518/how-to-compile-ffmpeg-2-2-2-on-windows-with-cygwin-and-android-ndk-r9c)

Comment: possible duplicate of [FFMPEG on Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4725773/ffmpeg-on-android)

Answer (score 1):

Based on my experience don't waste your time for compiling FFMPEG in Windows. It will be your worst nightmare & its the most difficult thing to compile.
Whenever you are compiling any libraries especially in **C**, **Windows OS**  is the worst OS, if you want to get your job done quickly don't think for a second **SWICTH** to **UBUNTU**. It will definely get compiled.

For Compilation you can also refer to

1. [Guardian Project](https://github.com/guardianproject/android-ffmpeg)
2. **[VLC- FFMPEG](http://git.videolan.org/?p=ffmpeg.git;a=summary) Refer to [VideoLan Wiki](https://wiki.videolan.org/VLC_media_player/)**

And last you can also use roman10. There are also projects like dolphin, etc. Google it and last thing keep patience.

If you have any problems with this let me know

Comment: Thanks James for your response, but i am looking this for on windows.if there any helpful tutorial or stuff please share it to me.it would be very great .

Comment: As I stated its impossible. I am saying this based on my experience. I have wasted . weeks for compiling FFMPEG in windows. Finally I quit and it was compiled in ubuntu. I request you switch to ubuntu or any unix OS. Don't waste your time for windows, just go to LINUX.

Comment: @chandanchaudhary One you started using linux you never go back to windows.

Comment: appreciate your advice..i will look into this as you stated for linux.

Comment: Best of luck let me  know if you have problems