# How to build ffmpeg with android-ndk-r10d in windows

Tags: android, android-ndk, ffmpeg

In my application user can selects several images and create movie(mp4) with those images, For this reason i want to use ffmpeg library.
i have searched more than 2 days but did not find a good tutorial for build ffmpeg with ndk in windows.

### can any body describe me, how to do that?(if you have any link, please share me)

i used [roman10](http://www.roman10.net/how-to-build-ffmpeg-with-ndk-r9/) tutorial and this is what i do:
1-i have decompressed "ffmpeg-2.6.2" folder into "android-ndk-r10d/sources".

2-i have created "build_android.sh" file into "ffmpeg-2.6.2" folder and these are my build_android.sh codes:

```
#!/bin/bash
NDK=C:/Users/HAKHASIN/Desktop/android-ndk-r10d

SYSROOT=$NDK/platforms/android-9/arch-arm/

TOOLCHAIN=$NDK/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.8/prebuilt/windows-x86_64

function build_one

{

./configure \

--prefix=$PREFIX \

--enable-shared \

--disable-static \

--disable-doc \

--disable-ffmpeg \

--disable-ffplay \

--disable-ffprobe \

--disable-ffserver \

--disable-avdevice \

--disable-doc \

--disable-symver \

--cross-prefix=$TOOLCHAIN/bin/arm-linux-androideabi- \

--target-os=linux \

--arch=arm \

--enable-cross-compile \

--sysroot=$SYSROOT \

--extra-cflags="-Os -fpic $ADDI_CFLAGS" \

--extra-ldflags="$ADDI_LDFLAGS" \

$ADDITIONAL_CONFIGURE_FLAG

make clean

make

make install

}

CPU=arm

PREFIX=$(pwd)/android/$CPU 

ADDI_CFLAGS="-marm"

build_one
```

3- when write "sudo chmod +x build_android.sh" and "./build_android.sh" commands in cygwin, it not work correctly

[image]

Comment: I'm absolutely sure that this is a very hard task, but show what you have already tried.

Comment: @rekire i have eddited my question, please read again. thanks

Comment: Have you tried to **chdir** to `ffmpeg-2.6.2`?

Comment: @AlexCohn yes, i sue ffmpeg-2.6.2.

Comment: I probably did not express myself clearly. You should run the script from `.../ffmpeg-2.6.2` directory, not from your home directory.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to compile ffmpeg-2.2.2 on windows with cygwin and android ndk r9c](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23683518/how-to-compile-ffmpeg-2-2-2-on-windows-with-cygwin-and-android-ndk-r9c)