# How to build and use ffmpeg libraries in Android project in Mac OS 10.9?

Tags: android, macos, android-ndk, ffmpeg, project

In my Android project I have to create a video from some pictures. So I want to use FFmpeg libraries for it. I read many links about it (For example: http://www.roman10.net/how-to-build-ffmpeg-with-ndk-r9/comment-page-4/) I tried to build FFmpeg in my computer (MAC OS 10.9) but every advice didn't work. 
Did anybody build and use FFmpeg in Adroid project (MAC OS) successfully? 
Can anybody give me some advices?
Sorry for my English!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For building ffmpeg for Android see the following answer: [Compiling FFmpeg lib and add it to NDK sources on Windows8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19892462/compiling-ffmpeg-lib-and-add-it-to-ndk-sources-on-windows8/19896512#19896512)

You can link to it in your project by adding what's written [here](http://www.kandroid.org/ndk/docs/PREBUILTS.html) in your Android.mk for each of the libraries you need from ffmpeg:

```
libavcodec.so
libavfilter.so
libavformat.so
libavutil.so
libswresample.so
libswscale.so
```

Also see this blog post: [How to Build ffmpeg with NDK r9](http://www.roman10.net/how-to-build-ffmpeg-with-ndk-r9/) which gives hands-on details on how to do it.

Comment: http://hunterford.me/compiling-ffmpeg-on-mac-os-x/  &  https://github.com/guardianproject/android-ffmpeg

Comment: You can also use this link to download the prebuilt FFMpeg libraries https://github.com/android-native-libraries